# Add addional parameter to function signature

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I use the following code which works as expected.
Now I want to add additional input to `modifyOpt` to be `modifyOpt(value)`
How should I do that?
Currently the modifyOpt are getting one parameter from findAPortAsync and I need to pass additional parameter from **outside**...(from the function which wraps all this promise)

```
return Promise.all([
    fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8').then(pars.getEx.bind(null, 'user')), 
    sync(3000, 4000, 'localhost').then(modifyOpt)
]).then(function(args) {
    return processExe('exec', args[0], args[1], args[1]);
})
```

I tried `modifyOpt(value)` and `modifyOpt.bind(value)` which didn't work

Comment: Why don't you just use the same approach as for passing the parameter to `pars.getEx`? How much of that code have you actually written yourself?

Comment: @Bergi - my friend my program is much more complicated (on the promise side)  here I just put some little example which help me to understand the promise concept(im new to javascript and mainly to the promise concept )...I believe also you give me 1- :(

Comment: This doesn't have much to do with promises, it's about passing arguments to callbacks. And you seem to know how to do that already, given `pars.getEx.bind(null, 'user')` in your code. So why do you ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call the function as `modifyOpt(value, port)`, this'll do:

```
.then(modifyOpt.bind(null, value))
```

The first argument to `bind` is the `this` value, function arguments follow...
You are already doing it correctly for `pars.getEx.bind`...

Of course, you can always just do this and use any argument order of your choice:

```
.then(function (port) { modifyOpt(port, value); })
```

Comment: Thanks I just having a problem with parameter order,btw which way is more preferable ? Im talking about the two options which you provide...

Comment: Whatever is necessary. Write your `modifyOpt` function the way it makes the most sense, use whatever way you need to "adapt" to it.